# SCD - for different supplier

Tags: sql, sql-server

can anyone suggest if they came across such scenario

i am getting data from different supllier SAY SUPPLIER A, SUPPLIER B and Supplier c...etc

i am implementing SCD TYPE 2.

What approach i should take to implement SCD-2.

currectly i am putting all supplier
data in a same table having different supplier id.

will it cause any problem when we load files from different supplier later time.

Your valuable suggestion helps me a lot

Thanks

Comment: What are you using? Is it Informatica?

Comment: @AkankshaSingh: sql server 2008. using merge

Comment: Can you add your table design and some example records?  Are there specific issues you are worried about?